# Hover Drop down - avoid repeated hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dropdown, mousehover

I came across this drop down menu navigation on Twilio's [website](http://twilio.com)
It slides a dropdown menu (with `<li>` contents) when hovering on a `<ul>`.

But when you hover on an adjacent `<ul>` tag, it swaps out the `<li>` tags instead of sliding out the current `<ul>` menu and sliding in the new `<ul>` menu, it simply swaps the `<li>` contents and resizes the container.

What's the best way to accomplish this

My Code so far: http://codepen.io/vlvgfx/pen/vNbYJe

Comment: use the .stop() jquery method. https://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/

Comment: @magreenberg I tried the method but couldnt make sense of it in context of the Twilio website menu demo. How is that done? The dropdown does not collapse but instead fades into the next dropdown..